# Performance issues updating multiple UI elements every second

Tags: android, performance, user-interface, timer, handler

**EDIT**: I've posted my solution below, (basically, ListViews are very slow for some reason), and will try to update it further if I can clarify why exactly a ListView is so awful in this situation.

**Objective:**

Get 7 ListView objects showing 7 independently set clocks/timers which update/tick every second.  These clocks are just Strings with a calculated elapsed time shown (SystemClock.ElapsedRealTime() - stored ElapsedRealTime() of when the object was instantiated.)

**The problem:**

Basically, 8 minutes into these 7 clocks ticking away - my program is essentially useless.. the information presented is inaccurate, the UI is pretty much unresponsive, etc.  Here are some results of testing against the benchmark of a physical stopwatch:

- At 04:00, clocks are slipping 1 second, and updating every 4 seconds.
- At 06:00, clocks are slipping 3 seconds, and updating every 5 seconds.
- At 08:00, clocks are slipping 6-7 seconds, and updating every 6 seconds.
- At 16:00, clocks are slipping 7 seconds, and updating every 10 seconds.

**What I have so far:**

I have a custom class, ActivityTimer, with a stored long representing the SystemClock.ElapsedRealTime() of when each ActivityTimer was first instantiated.  By clicking on a Button 7 times, I instantiate 7 of these, each of which are added to an ArrayList

I have a compound view, ActivityTimerControl, which is passed an ActivityTimer upon instantiation, and then presents data elements of my ActivityTimer in UI elements (such as the ticking clock.)  My ArrayAdapter handles this instantiation and works fine.  As per [this fine tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html) I have a _Handler in this ActivityControl, which upon construction of the ActvityControl posts this:

```
private Runnable _timerUpdateTask = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        final long start = _ActivityTimer.getStartTime();
        long millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - start;
        int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
        int minutes = seconds / 60;
        seconds     = seconds % 60;
        if (seconds < 10) 
        {
            _tglActivityPauseButton.setTextOn(""+minutes+":0"+seconds);
        } 
        else 
        {
            _tglActivityPauseButton.setTextOn("" + minutes + ":" + seconds);            
        }
        _tglActivityPauseButton.setChecked(true);
        _timerUpdateHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
};
```

Other than what I've described my project really doesn't do anything yet, as I've been stuck on this fundamental issue so far.  So I haven't posted any other code because I just don't think its relevant beyond the summaries I've given above - but if anyone feels some other part of the project is relevant just let me know and I'll post the detailed code for it.  I'm presenting my final String into the SetTextOn() of a ToggleButton, but testing has shown that this isn't a significant factor - it doesn't matter whether I'm setting the Text of a normal TextView, or what, no matter what I've tried my results are always roughly the same, with noticable lag on each clock and eventually the UI becoming unresponsive completely.

My understanding is that a Handler is supposed to be the most efficient way of updating a UI element on a consistent and frequent basis, replacing java.util.Timer, but despite this my code starts out slow and just gets worst the longer I let it run.

Even upon increasing the postDelay to 5000ms, the same problems still occured and the app still force closed after 49 minutes.  Since I would have thought this test would have extended the time til force-close by 5, if not fixing it altogether (at the detriment to the functionality I want), I'm suspecting that something isn't recycling right with the handler or some other component.

**My Questions:**

- I suspect my problem is in having 7 objects (ActivityControls), each of which has *its own* Handler constantly cycling the update of the corresponding time that's displayed.  Does anyone have experience to say if this would be the case?
- Is there a way I can have a *single* Handler that calls upon each ActivityControl in my ListView to update its time?
- Does posting a message to the Handler leave some memory trace that doesn't dispose automatically, or might benefit from being forced to dispose?
- Does anyone else have other ideas about the most efficient way of running constant UI updates on multiple objects?

Answer (score 0):

you are delaying by 1sec

_timerUpdateHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

You have not allowed anytime for your code to run.

Comment: 1 second is how often I want the clock to update.  The delay waits for that second before calling for another iteration of updating the text.  I would think 1 second is plenty of time for the code I've listed to run, it's not that many instructions, and most phones have 1ghz processors.  Is there something specific about the code that leads you to believe it's taking more than a second to run, or are you inferring it from the backlog evident in the test results I posted?  I'll update it to 5 seconds and let it run, just to see if it will stay consistent with that for over an hour at least.

Comment: Just for additional info, here's the results of setting the postDelay to 5000ms:  
  
+ Slipping 1 second at 04:00.  UI Updates every 5 seconds (par).
+ Slipping 3 seconds at 08:00.  UI updates every 8 seconds (3 seconds slow.)
+ Slipping 8-9 seconds at 16:00.  UI Updates every 11-13 seconds (6-8 seconds slow)

Comment: ... Aaand, the app finally locked up completely and force closed at 49 minutes.  This actually surprised me, I was expecting that decreasing updates to every 5 seconds instead of every 1 second would have a much more significant impact - extending the time til force close by a factor of 5 I would have thought.  This really leads me to believe something isn't recycling properly and letting go of memory resources

Answer (score 0):

Ugh.. wouldn't you know it.. this isn't a problem with my Handler, or anything else like that.  It's either an inefficiency with a ListView, or some funkiness that takes place in an ArrayAdapter (the one I was using was as simple as it gets though.)  I made a sandbox project (below) and instantiated my 7 ActivityTimers right into an ArrayList, and then iterated through that array using each object to instantiate an ActivityControl that's passed a copy of that ActivityTimer from the array.  Everything I was doing previously, but replacing the ListView with a LinearLayout contained in a ScrollView.  After 16 minutes I've got 7 ActivityControls ticking away roughly every single second, and keeping accurate time.  Even after 30 minutes, showing no slight hint of problems (as it should be!)  Here's what I did:

```
public class Sandbox_Experiments extends Activity {
ArrayList<com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer> _ActivityTimers = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _ActivityTimers = new ArrayList<com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer>();
    View myLayout =  findViewById(R.id.Info);

    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act1 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();
    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act2 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();
    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act3 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();
    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act4 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();
    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act5 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();
    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act6 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();
    com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer act7 = new com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer();


    _ActivityTimers.add(act1);
    __ActivityTimers.add(act2);
    __ActivityTimers.add(act3);
    __ActivityTimers.add(act4);
    __ActivityTimers.add(act5);
    __ActivityTimers.add(act6);
    __ActivityTimers.add(act7);


    for (int i = 0; i < __ActivityTimers.size(); i++)
    {
        ActivityControl ac = new ActivityControl(this, (com.maxx233.Sandbox.ActivityTimer)__ActivityTimers.get(i));
        ac.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        ((LinearLayout)myLayout).addView(ac);
    }
}
```

}

So I'll work on figuring out what spcifically it is about having a ListView in the equation that causes such a problem, and then I'll update this thread in case anyone else is having a similar problem ever.  Unless someone else out there happens to already know why a ListView would make updating a handful of objects each second so much more resource intensive?